# How can I sum data in a multidimensional object in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  styleUrls: ["./styles.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./template.html"
})
export class MyRouteData {
  MyDataObject: object;
  MyDataObjectTotals: object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("http://localhost:5000/MyRoute/GetMyData")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.MyDataObject = response;
      });
  }
}
```

which stores the following data in the MyDataObject object:

```
{
  "Record1": {
    "CustomerName": "Obi Wan Kenobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":2,
    "SalesTotal":10.04
  },
  "Record2": {
    "CustomerName": "Darth Vader",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-02",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Burn Cream 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":200000,
    "SalesTotal":7523840.84
  },
  "Record3": {
    "CustomerName": "Luke Skywalker",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-02",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Power Converters",
    "QuantityPurchased":5,
    "SalesTotal":1324.02
  },
  "Record4": {
    "CustomerName": "Jabba the Hut",
    "TransactionDate": "2019-01-05",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Dancing Slave Chick",
    "QuantityPurchased":1,
    "SalesTotal":150000.00
  }
}
```

Please note that the GetMyData endpoint is running a SQL query that returns a table. I have just represented the data as JSON here so it can be viewed easily.
The columns the SQL query returns are CustomerName, TransactionDate, IsNewCustomer, ItemPuchased, QuantityPurchased, and SalesTotal.

I would like to store the totals of each column (where relevant) into another object (the MyDataObjectTotals in the code above).

I am able to total a single column with the following code:

```
var QuantityPurchasedColumn = MyDataObject.map(a => a.QuantityPurchased);
var QuantityPurchasedTotal = QuantityPurchasedColumn.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;});
```

Is there a generic method I can write to just give it an object (i.e MyDataObject) and it will return me an object with the following data (again, not a JSON string but an object with the CustomerName, TransactionDate, IsNewCustomer, ItemPuchased, QuantityPurchased, and SalesTotal columns):

```
{
    "CustomerName": null,
    "TransactionDate": null,
    "IsNewCustomer": null,
    "ItemPuchased":null,
    "QuantityPurchased": 200008,
    "SalesTotal": 7675174.90
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your statement that you successfully used `map`, I'm assuming you intended `MyDataObject` to be an array instead of an object as shown in the question.  You can iterate over the keys of the first record using a for-in loop and check, for each key, whether you want a sum or `null`.

```
var MyDataObject = [
  {
    "CustomerName": "Obi Wan Kenobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased": "Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased": 2,
    "SalesTotal": 10.04
  },
  {
    "CustomerName": "Darth Vader",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-02",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased": "Burn Cream 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased": 200000,
    "SalesTotal": 7523840.84
  },
  {
    "CustomerName": "Luke Skywalker",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-02",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased": "Power Converters",
    "QuantityPurchased": 5,
    "SalesTotal": 1324.02
  },
  {
    "CustomerName": "Jabba the Hut",
    "TransactionDate": "2019-01-05",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased": "Dancing Slave Chick",
    "QuantityPurchased": 1,
    "SalesTotal": 150000.00
  }
];
type MyRecord = typeof MyDataObject[number];

var SumColumns: Partial<{ [K in keyof MyRecord]:
  MyRecord[K] extends number ? true : never }> = {
  "QuantityPurchased": true,
  "SalesTotal": true
};

var Sum = <{ [K in keyof MyRecord]: number | null }>{};
let columnName: keyof MyRecord;
for (columnName in MyDataObject[0]) { 
  Sum[columnName] = SumColumns[columnName]
    ? MyDataObject.map(a => <number>a[columnName]).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; })
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try JSON.Parse(myObject) method? That will convert your JSON object into the JS object.

Comment: i believe angular's HttpClient already parse the data in json format.

Comment: I know that but @woody was asking how he can change Jason string into object.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 different ways to solve this.
**1. Iterate over the json keys.**

```
var myObj = {

  "Record1": {
    "CustomerName": "Obi Wan Kenobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":2,
    "SalesTotal":10.04
  },
    "Record2": {
    "CustomerName": "Oobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":2,
    "SalesTotal":10.04
  },
};

for (var values in myObj) {
  console.log(myObj[values]['QuantityPurchased']);
}
```

**2. Instead of sending json of Records, send array of Records**

```
var myObj: Records[] = [

   {
    "CustomerName": "Obi Wan Kenobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":2,
    "SalesTotal":10.04
  },
 {
    "CustomerName": "Oobi",
    "TransactionDate": "2018-01-01",
    "IsNewCustomer": false,
    "ItemPuchased":"Speeder Polish 250ml",
    "QuantityPurchased":2,
    "SalesTotal":10.04
  },
];

myObj.forEach(myRecord => {
  // Do w/e you like.
});
```

Comment: For the first example you gave, whenever you iterate an object, use this method in an if conditional inside the loop: hasOwnProperty. This method checks if the property belongs to the object. You can see more here: https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/

Comment: @ArmandoPerez: thanks for reminding me this. I'm almost forgot about it.

Comment: Anytime pal! :)